# Vertx connection timeout not catched JDBCClient (.getConnection)

Tags: java, vert.x

I can't handle case when connection failed in JDBCClient, example: no host to route, connection time out and etc. Because the method .getConnection() is not return failedFuture but it show cause in monitor then it's will silence.
I think it should send the fail future more than print error log when connection time out or other cause.

My example code is.

```
JDBCClient client = ...;
client.getConnection(conn -> {
    if (conn.succeeded()) {
        ....
    } else {
        // This is never executed (connection time out and etc.)
        handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(conn.cause()));
    }
});
```

i got this Error in logs:

```
An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118) 
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77) 
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:690) 
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140) 
    at JDBCClient.lambda$getConnection$1(JDBCClient.java:132) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@16404129 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1467) 
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644) 
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554) 
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758) 
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685) 
    ... 5 more
```

Someone can help me please.

thank you.

Comment: I guess the problem has been solved with recent vertx versions? Because I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make something like this:

```
  public Future<SQLConnection> tryConnect() {
    JDBCClient client = JDBCClient.createNonShared(vertx, config());
    Future<SQLConnection> future = Future.future();
    client.getConnection(it -> {
      if (it.succeeded()) {
        future.complete(it.result());
      } else {
        future.fail(it.cause());
      }
    });
    return future;
  }
```

Just create future manually and then resolve or reject it in the callback. It's actually common approach for such cases.

Comment: it's the same, the problem is that client.getConnection is never return the future result, so when you do if (it.succeeded()) {
        future.complete(it.result());
      } else {
        future.fail(it.cause());
      } well never excute the future.complete(it.result()); or future.fail(it.cause());

Comment: I got, it seems that problem is wrong jdbc configuration, or your database is shut down. Could you provide more details about the database?

Comment: yes, when the database is shutdown i have this problem, so if i set a timer in the result of the future it well not execute

Comment: I am not sure that I understand you correctly, you will always get an error if your database is shut down. What the problem? Check your database

Comment: the problem is that when the database is shut down i don't catch this in the future of client.getConnection