# Vertx Failed Connection issue not catched JDBCClient (.getConnection)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, vert.x

I can't handle case when connection failed in JDBCClient on vertx-jdbc-client - 3.3.9, example: no host to route, connection time out and etc. Because the method .getConnection() does not return failedFuture and failed is not called even on wrong hostname, username and passwords.

The method only gets executed successfully when all the provided parameters for a connection is valid else the block of code gets stuck and SQLConnection is never called. Even wrapping the code with try catch block gives no error in my case.

```
JDBCClient client = JDBCClient.createNonShared(Holder.getInstance().getVertx(), databaseConfig);
            client.getConnection(connect -> {
                if (connect.failed()){
                    client.close();
                    return;
                }
/* Create connection on success */
SQLConnection connection = connect.result();
/* Execute Query */
```

Related: [Vertx connection timeout not catched JDBCClient (.getConnection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264092/vertx-connection-timeout-not-catched-jdbcclient-getconnection)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the C3P0 connection pool, try this:

```
databaseConfig.put("acquire_retry_attempts", 1).put("break_after_acquire_failure", true);
```

Otherwise the pool keeps trying to establish a connection.

Comment: It look like the following options are not available in the vertx-jdbc-client - 3.3.x For now it is not possible to upgrade the vertx-jdbc-client version. There is a mention of c3p0.properties to add the additional parameter. I will try to implement those and if you have previously used it as configuration in vertx any help would be appreciated.